# How to put a face on a coin?

Tags: photo-editing, effects, corel-paint-shop-pro

I'm new to Corel PaintShop, and I recently purchased a copy of PaintShop Pro X8 Ultimate. I've been following the tutorials and learning the basics, but I can't find an example of what I'm attempting for my next image project.

I want to take a photo of a side-profile of a person's face, and put it on a coin. Below is the coin that I'm planning to use as the target. It's no problem to use the PSP object remover to scrub out the Queen's face (no disrespect intended) and the lettering. Next I need to learn how to take a regular photo of a person's face and transform it so it looks appropriate for the 'heads' side of the coin.

Can anyone suggest what features of PSP X8 I would need to use to achieve this kind of transformation? I'm rather overwhelmed by all the features of PSP, so I don't know how to get started.

---

*EDIT*
This is the image I started with:
[image]

This is the image after I removed the existing head and some of the lettering:
[image]

Comment: Hi Jim, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question? Could you please show us a couple of things you have tried wit no luck? We'd really like to help you, but we are not a 'request-a-tutorial' site. If you could show us some efforts and the point in the process you're getting stuck, we will be way more able to help you. Thanks! If you have any questions, have a look at the [help] or join us in [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is not on the realm of Paint Shop, you have a bigger one. No normal photo in the world has the 3D information to do this. You need a real 3D model.

No religious discussion intended, but an example on how a 3D portrait looks like is this: [image]

Where the shadow areas and the bright ones give a height info. Normally dark for deeper parts. That is called a **bump map or displacement map**.

On a normal photo the shadow areas indicate not distances, but "shadows" or dark colors.

This discards some possible technique of **emboss**.

### The options

#### 3D model

You make a real 3D model fo a persons head http://www.123dapp.com/catch pass it to a 3D rendering program like blender, asign materials, etc.

#### Lighting and painting

- Take a photo of the person with a simmilar ilumination and angle of the photo of the coin.
- Make it grayscale and move the curves to achive simmilar contrast.
- Mask the dark color parts like the hair to adjust the contrast accordingly.
- As you already cleaned the image, use the resulting portrait with "multiply" mode.
- Retouch by hand.

#### Try some displacement maps photography tricks and software

For example this resources: http://www.zarria.net/nrmphoto/nrmphoto.html

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-do-i-make-a-normal-displacement-map-when-all-i-have-is-a-photo

Using the resulted image, after some retouches, you now can use an emboss filter on Paint Shop.

#### Paint it yourself

- Using the photo as a basis. You need practicly to sculpt the simulated 3D shape on top of the image, painting light and shadows.

Comment: Thanks Rafael! This is the kind of info I wanted. I'll attempt what you've suggested and see if I can achieve a decent result.

Comment: I added a point as you showed the cleaned image. Use multiply mode on top of the coin.